# Ember Validations: Custom Validator Setup

Tags: ember.js, ember-validations

I'm using Ember 2.3 and DockYard's ember-validations version "2.0.0-alpha.4". I'm using POD structure on my project.

No matter with predefined validations but I'm facing with injection problems while using custom validators.

As mentioned in [documentation](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-validations#custom-validators), I've placed my validators at *my-app/app/validators/* directory. But they are not loaded.
If I manually inject them by using a factory, they work. But ember-validations couldn't load them automatically.

How can I make ember-validations to load my custom validators?

**UPDATE**

Since no one answered for months, and [the documentation issue](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-validations/issues/402) was also not answered, we wrote our own validation addon. It takes about 3 weeks for a single developer. But works well for our needs.